# Boost 1.44 --builddir and --includedir not working in Windows?

Tags: windows, boost, build, bjam

I'm trying to build Boost 1.44 into a certain directory instead of the default. I do the same thing on my linux machine by doing the following steps from the boost root directory:

./bootstrap.sh
bjam --prefix=../../DIR

which builds the libs into ../../DIR/lib and the headers into ../../DIR/include.

I'm trying to do the same thing on my windows machine, so i tried:

./bootstrap
bjam--prefix=../../DIR

but that built it straight into the boost root build area.
I also tried
bjam --builddir=../../DIR/lib --includedir=../../DIR/include

but none of this seems to work. Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a full path?

Comment: Yeah, I tried a full path as well, but still no luck

Comment: I am using the "fast build method," so I am just building using the existing Bjam that comes with the boost source. Do i need to download the latest BJam seperatly?

Comment: @Nik: No, the existing bjam works fine here -- the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at --includedir, the layout option is important. 
Under Windows, the default is "versioned" which means that the boost version is placed in the directory path. Conversely, under Linux "system" is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try using \ instead of / when specifying the directories. For what it's worth, I use this on Windows:

```
bjam --libdir=..\boost_1_39_0\lib --includedir=..\boost_1_39_0\include --with-date_time --with-filesystem --with-thread --build-type=complete toolset=msvc-9.0 install
```

Not sure if that helps at all, but it's a thought at least.

Answer (score 0):

alright, after a bit of messing around, I think I finally got it. Thanks to sgolodetz to leading me to the answer.

after doing: 
.\bjam --prefix ....\ install

things seemed to build into the places I needed them. I don't remember needing to type install on linux, but i have a bad memory.

the headers still build into ....\boost_1_44\boost instead of just ....\boost but I can always copy them out

Thanks for all your help